# can I use CC BY-SA 3.0 media (pictures) in a software partly licensed under a non-derivative license?

Tags: licensing, copyright, copyleft, multi-licensing, cc-by-sa

I am working on software that contains graphics I didn't make, that are licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0.

Since the software contains other parts I didn't make, I want to put it under two different licenses. All the stuff I didn't/partly make will be put under the license it was under before, and my stuff will be put under some non-derivative license.

Now I'm worried that Copyleft may not allow me to do so.
(because media is under CC BY-SA 3.0 and my software is based on it, it must be under CC BY-SA 3.0, too (strong copyleft) (?))

Anyway, this conclusion seems quite senseless to me, because CC BY-SA 3.0 isn't a software license.

Can I put the software under a dual license as mentioned before?

Comment: The answer depends to a large extent on how your software is related to the graphics it contains. So, how are the software and graphics related to each other? Would the software *function* differently if you would use other graphics, or would the application just *look* slightly differently?

Comment: look different. (that are textures for a game)